# "Working on it" message - Handle event and hide some blocks

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I edited master page, added some custom blocks.

My problem is when opening the web site I see my footer and header blocks.

How can I hide these blocks when "Working on it" block appears?

[image: Screenshot]

Can I handle JavaScript event or should I apply SharePoint CSS classes like "s4-notdlg" to hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Applying the CSS class `s4-notdlg` to all HTML elements of your custom masterpage you want to hide should do the trick.